# Dividing conference attendees into unique groups

Tags: combinatorics

How can I divide 20 people up into groups of 5 for 6 different break out sessions where none of the groups contain the same people.

The idea is to get everybody to meet the others and work in different group dynamics.

Comment: For how many break out sessions? There will be some overlap in any case.

Comment: There are two sessions a day for three day for a total of 6 sessions.

Comment: The search term you want is *combinatorial designs*. Also, this bears some similarity to "the social golfer problem", which see.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are separating the 20 people into groups of 5, and that you are doing 6 sessions.

I created a simulation using C#. Each person is denoted by a letter (A, B, C, etc). So far, the best combination I have gotten is

Session #1
ABCDE · FGHIJ · KLMNO · PQRST
Session #2
ABHMR · CFGNS · DIKLT · EJOPQ
Session #3
ABIOS · CHKLQ · DFGMP · EJNRT
Session #4
AFGKR · EJLMS · CDHOT · BINPQ
Session #5
AJKLP · BFGOT · CIMQR · DEHNS
Session #6
AMNQT · BDJOR · CHKPS · EFGIL

[image]

Stats:

Number of meetings of pairs that met...

> More than once: 58

Never: 8
Once: 135
Twice: 40
3 times: 10
4 times: 3
5 times: 0
6 times: 5

"58 meetings of pairs that met more than once" is the lowest I have gotten so far. It is very likely that there is a better combination. I will keep running it, and update this post with any improved results.

Notice also that even in this best case (so far) scenario, 8 pairs of people never meet at all!

Comment: That is awesome, thank you.

Comment: Hold on. I just tweaked it a lot. Posting improved answer now.